# QGIS 3.0.2 in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, anaconda, qgis

I installed the QGIS package for Anaconda Navigator (AN) into a dedicated environment .  When executing the "qgis" command from a terminal in the activated  environment, the following error results:

[image: conda qgis startup error w/dependencies shown]

It seems like there might be an environmental variable deficiency somewhere, because the "qgis_app.dll" file exists within the folder where qgis.exe is located, despite the errors indicating otherwise.

What are the best troubleshooting steps for such a problem?

Comment: I just ran into the exact same problem, and am wondering if there should be a .env file created there specifying path to qgis.exe?

Comment: Also raised here: https://github.com/conda-forge/qgis-feedstock/issues/43